# Review queue: if you don't want to fix it, Skip instead of No Action Needed

Tags: discussion

I'm seeing a lot of questions with obvious grammar errors like "geotagging aerial photo's" passed through the review queue. If you are looking at the queue and see something like this but don't feel like fixing it, please press **Skip** instead of No Action Needed.

Many other questions could at least use better tags,  which is very helpful for future searches.

Or, if you don't think improving questions in this way is important, that's fine — but please don't use the review queue. The questions you say don't need action get taken out of the queue and then aren't reviewed by people who might make the effort.

Comment: Big +1 item here...

Comment: I agree. I'd also note that the review queues almost always seem to be empty when I take a look at them, which has always felt a little unusual. Every so often I find a few things in the close queue, but for the most part, our overall review queues seem to be at zero 90% of the time or more.

Comment: Does the review queue have a log so we can just tell the offender to stop directly?

Comment: @dpollitt: Not directly...it only shows who took action, not what they took action on.

Comment: @dpollitt Actually, there is a post-by-post history [here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history), which isn't surprising given Stack Exchange's generally open approach. I didn't want to name names because my goal wasn't to pick on particular individuals. And of course there often *are* cases where "No Action" is the appropriate choice. (Although, honestly, pretty rarely in the first post queue.)

Comment: Yeah we don't want to turn off people who do genuinely review the queue to doing so in the future, but instead just coach them on the proper usage of the queue. Hey @MikeW and Håkon K. Olafsen I'm assuming since you two are the most active review queue users that this would help you two out! Thanks for reviewing and all since I'm too lazy to do so :)

Comment: @Håkon K. Olafsen since I can only notify one person per comment...

Comment: I wasn't aware no one else would see it on the queue if a single person said No Action.   I was under the impression at least 3 people would see it in the Review queue.  Not sure where I got that idea.  I'm pretty good at picking up spelling and grammar, but I probably don't pay attention enough to tags tbh. I'll keep that in mind.